# ¿Cual patron usar en esta situación?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo una aplicación empresarial sencilla en java. La aplicación se basa en guardar clientes y cuando el usuario requiera ver los datos de cada uno, en un `JTree` lo seleccione y se muestre un `JPanel` con sus datos. Para realizarlo estoy usando el patrón `MVC` y acá viene el problema, mi vista nesecita dos tipos de `Listeners`, uno del tipo `ActionListener` y otro del tipo `TreeSelectionListener`. Ahora, yo lo que suelo hacer, es que a mi vista principal le agrego como parámetro al constructor(o en ocaciones lo hago en un setter) un `ActionListener` pero ahora que tengo dos no quiero tener que depender de dos parámetros para instanciar mi vista, pienso que debe haber una mejor forma de hacerlo, ej: Alguna clase factory, alguna clase helper(con las variables estáticas) pero, antes de meter manos al código, quiero saber cúal sería la mejor opción.

***CÓDIGO:***

```
     public class ApplicationWindow extends JFrame {

    private List<Cliente> clientes = new LinkedList<>();
    private ActionListener actionListener;

    //Panels
    private ClientTree clientTree; 
    private CenterPane centerPane;

    //Menu
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenuItem fileMenuItem = new JMenuItem("File");
    private JMenuItem editMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Edit");
    private JMenuItem viewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("View");

    public ApplicationWindow(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Window
        this.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Left pane.
        clientTree = new ClientTree(clientes,actionListener);

        //Center pane.
        centerPane = new CenterPane();
        centerPane.setBackground(Color.red);

        //Add menuBar
        menuBar.add(fileMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(editMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(viewMenuItem);

        //Add
        add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(clientTree,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);



    }



    public void updateClients(List<Cliente> newClientes) {
        clientes = newClientes;
    }






    public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }
    public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
    }




}
```

Este es el código de la ventana principal. Por si no me explique bien, nesecito un `ActionListener`(el cual ya tengo) y además un `TreeSelectionListener` pero no quiero tener que depender de 2 `Listeners` en mi constructor o acordarme de que antes de usar mi ventana, nesecito settearselos. Por lo que la duda sería alguna forma(correcta) en donde yo simplemente lo configure y no dependa de settearlos o de un constructor mas grande.

Comment: ¿Crees que puedas agregar la parte relevante del código para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Podría pero no creo que se vaya a entender mejor. El problema básicamente es la idea, cómo estructurar esta parte del código.

Comment: Quizás puedas tener implementaciones dummy que no hagan nada con el listener, pero necesitaría ver el código para comprender mejor tu situación y proponer una mejor alternativa.

Comment: Listo, ya agregué el código.

Comment: Recordar que los `Listeners` son interfaces y que una clase puede implementar múltiples interfaces y sobrescribir los métodos que requiere reescribir. No me queda claro tu concepto de vista (si es un componente en particular o que), recordar también que puedes usar un `instance of` para determinar el tipo de objeto que genera el evento.

Comment: Mmm no está quedando clara mi pregunta . Gracias igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto `ActionListener` como `TreeSelectionListener` son interfaces que extienden de la interfaz `EventListener`. En virtud de esta herencia (Clase A extiende de clase C o clase B implementa la clase C), es posible pasar como argumentos de un método que espera un objeto que es una instancia de una clase C cualquier objeto que sea subtipo de la clase C (en este caso, una instancia de la clase A o la clase B).

Es posible implementar el código del constructor de su clase `ApplicationWindow` de tal forma que uno de sus argumentos sea un objeto de tipo `EventListener`. De esta forma, el código cliente que llame a su código podrá, al invocar el constructor, pasarle una variable de tipo `ActionListener` o de tipo `TreeSelectionListener`.

```
public ApplicationWindow(EventListener eventListener) {
    //Lógica del constructor
    //...
}
```

En tiempo de ejecución, sin embargo, deberá modificar la implementación del constructor para verificar si el objeto enviado es un subtipo de `ActionListener` o de `TreeSelectionListener`. Esto es debido a que, si bien heredan de `EventListener`, siguen siendo interfaces y por lo tanto los métodos que su clase `ClientTree` use de estos listeners son absolutamente distintos y sólo los objetos que implementen o bien `ActionListener` o bien `TreeSelectionListener` conocen.

Ahora bien, si el problema es que debe poder recibir *ambos* listeners y usar *ambos* al mismo tiempo, es necesario modificar el constructor para recibir o bien ambos listeners como dos parámetros distintos o un arreglo de listeners de tipo `EventListener` donde el código cliente sea el encargado de instanciar estos objetos.

```
public ApplicationWindow(ActionListener actionListener, TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener) {
    //Lógica del constructor
    //...
}
```

La solución anterior tiene sentido ya que el constructor en realidad está suministrando los listeners a la clase `ClientTree` en el constructor y esta es quien en últimas decidirá bajo cuáles eventos invocará a los listeners correspondientes (no es posible dar más información al respecto porque no se suministra la implementación de esta clase). De otro lado:

```
public ApplicationWindow(EventListener[] eventListener) {
    //Lógica del constructor
    //...
}
```

pasar en el argumento del constructor un arreglo de tipo EventListener permite lograr una escalabilidad en el número de objetos de este tipo que se pueden usar, pero ocurrirá el mismo inconveniente: al ser muy diferentes las dos implementaciones de los objetos de tipo `ActionListener` y `TreeSelectionListener`, sería muy natural que esta separación de intereses estuviera bien definida en la implementación de la clase ClientTree. En este sentido, **cualquier patrón de diseño que use herencia como solución no tiene sentido porque, si las implementaciones finales de estas interfaces tienen una API absolutamente distinta, no sería posible aprovechar el polimorfismo que se logra en virtud de la herencia.**

Answer (score 0):

Si usas inyección de dependencias no necesitas inicializar el listener en el constructor. Por ejemplo, usando [Spring](https://spring.io/), tu atributo quedaría así:

```
@Autowired
private TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener;
```